# Pytorch Lightning limit_val_batches and val_check_interval behavior

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I'm setting `limit_val_batches=10` and `val_check_interval=1000` so that I'm validating on 10 validation batches every 1000 training steps. Is it guaranteed that Trainer will use the same 10 batches every time validation is called?

I tried search the source code for `limit_val_batches` but couldn't figure out how it was being used to obtain the validation batches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer doesn't have much to do with PyTorch Lightning and its flags (`--limit_val_batches` and `--val_check_interval`). The exact batches of data provided by Lightning inside any of the

```
def *_step(self, batch, ...):
    ...
```

methods (`*` is training/validation/test) is determined by the underlying PyTorch `DataLoader`s returned by

```
def *_dataloder(...):
    return DataLoader(dataset, shuffle=..., sampler=..., batch_sampler=...)
```

If the dataloader returned by these functions DO NOT have `shuffle=True` or any randomized `Sampler`s, the **batches will be same**.

As far as `--limit_val_batches=N` is concerned, it fetches first `N` batches from the underlying dataloader. Lightning doesn't do any data selection by itself. It is confirmed by a core developer [here](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/2928#issuecomment-672939229).